# Unable to run apt update: At least one invalid signature was encountered

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

My Linux Mint 20 installation suddenly stopped updating. Update Manger says "Your APT configuration is corrupt". Running apt update produces the following messages:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease [18,1 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]                
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease 
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Ign:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana InRelease                           
Get:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana Release [24,1 kB]                   
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana Release.gpg [833 B]                 
Ign:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana Release.gpg   
Get:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [12,1 kB]            
Err:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana Release: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried running apt clean, but this did not resolve the issue.
Also, apt-key list gives the following strange message:

```
base64: invalid input
```

Please help.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove  ...   Start with sudo apt-get autoclean is the first app prevents the remainder to execute. This might possibly work.

Comment: No, unfortunately apt-get clean and apt-get autoclean do not fix the problem.

Comment: You may need to back up what you can and reinstall Linux.

Comment: That's just the answer I was afraid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution for my case!

`apt-get update` wrote that in many repos "At least one invalid signature was encountered." There were no messages about missed GPG keys. Exactly like your output, but other repos.

I run `apt-key list` and somewhere in between i noticed `base64: invalid input` message.

This was somewhere in the middle of my output

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nordvpn-keyring.gpg
------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-08-02 [SC]
      BC54 80EF EC5C 081C E5BC  FBE2 6B21 9E53 5C96 4CA1
uid           [ unknown] NordVPN <admin@nordvpn.com>
sub   rsa4096 2018-08-02 [S]

base64: invalid input      <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEM 
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/steam.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2012-12-07 [SC]
      BA18 16EF 8E75 005F CF5E  27A1 F24A EA9F B054 98B7
uid           [ unknown] Valve Corporation <linux@steampowered.com>
sub   rsa2048 2012-12-07 [E]
```

I found that it means that there is bad key file in a folder `/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` between `nordvpn-keyring.gpg` and `steam.gpg` (alphabetical order of files). In my case there were two strange files with not .gpg extension. These files were newer than others. This was another clue about their involvement.

I deleted them and suddenly everything started to work!

It seems that all key files that was listed after those two was not worked.

// Linux Mint 19

Answer (score 1):

If `apt-get update`,  `apt-get autoclean`, `sudo apt-get clean` are not working, and if you're not using it, you could try to manually remove the source causing you the problem by modifying (using nano, vim, or whatever) the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
Otherwise you could try to manually add the missing/corrupt GPG keys of the sources you need with `wget -qO - <link_to_source_key> | sudo apt-key add -`